# carousel with clickable card not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this carousel with card divs wrapped inside an `href` so users can click the card. Right now I can only slide the card but it's not clickable.

If I remove `pointer-events: none;` from `.inner-slider` then the card is clickable, but I cannot slide the carousel smoothly and it's all jumpy when I tried to slide it.

How can I fix this?

```js
let sliderContainer = document.querySelector(".slider-container");
let innerSlider = document.querySelector(".inner-slider");
let banner = document.querySelector(".banner");

let pressed = false;
let startX;
let x;
let bannerOpacity = banner.style.opacity
let oldx = 0

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  pressed = true;
  startX = e.offsetX - innerSlider.offsetLeft;
  sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grabbing";
});

// sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
//     sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grab";
// });

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  sliderContainer.style.cursor = "default";
});

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grab";
  pressed = false;
});

window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  // pressed = false;
});

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (!pressed) return;

  console.log(`e.pageX:${e.pageX};oldx:${oldx};op:${banner.style.opacity}`);
  console.log(banner.style.opacity + 1);
  if (e.pageX > oldx && banner.style.opacity < 1) {
    banner.style.opacity = parseFloat(banner.style.opacity) + 0.01;
    console.log('right');
  } else if (e.pageX < oldx && banner.style.opacity > 0) {
    console.log('left');
    banner.style.opacity -= 0.01
  }
  e.preventDefault();

  x = e.offsetX;

  innerSlider.style.left = `${x - startX}px`;
  oldx = e.pageX;
  checkBoundary();
});

const checkBoundary = () => {
  let outer = sliderContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
  let inner = innerSlider.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (parseInt(innerSlider.style.left) > 150) {
    innerSlider.style.left -= 10;
    // bannerOpacity -= 0.01
  }

  if (inner.right < outer.right) {
    innerSlider.style.left = `-${inner.width - outer.width}px`;
  }
};
```

```css
.card {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.banner {
  z-index: 2;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

.card:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}


/* .card:first-child {
        visibility: hidden;
    } */

.card:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(0, 183, 255);
}

.slider-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-slider {
  width: 150%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="banner" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
  <div class="inner-slider">
    <!-- <div class="card"></div> -->
    <a href="google.com">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CodePen Link: https://codepen.io/mjkno1/pen/zYWPjEw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

Changes made:

- make cards as `<div>` blocks instead of `<a>` and save the block link in the data attribute
- whenever a user clicks on the card, check if it's a "mousemove" event or "click" - if mouse moved more then `clickDelta` value assume it's a move, otherwise - click. If click - make redirect programmatically to the url stored in the data attribute
- some changes made to the way how we calculate new position for the slider `innerSlider.style.left`. Memorise the initial position of the slider and add "move delta".

Hope this makes sense

```js
   let sliderContainer = document.querySelector(".slider-container");
    let innerSlider = document.querySelector(".inner-slider");
    let banner = document.querySelector(".banner");

    const clickDelta = 5;
    let pressed = false;

    let startX;
    let blockPos;

    let clickStartX;
    let clickStartY;
    let clickedTarget;

    let x;
    let bannerOpacity = banner.style.opacity;
    let oldx = 0;

    sliderContainer.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
      pressed = true;
      startX = e.pageX;
      blockPos = parseInt(innerSlider.style.left, 10) || 0;
      sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grabbing";
    });

    sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
      sliderContainer.style.cursor = "default";
    });

    sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
      sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grab";
      pressed = false;
    });

    innerSlider.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
      clickedTarget = e.target;
      clickStartX = event.pageX;
      clickStartY = event.pageY;
    });

    innerSlider.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
      const deltaX = Math.abs(event.pageX - clickStartX);
      const deltaY = Math.abs(event.pageY - clickStartY);

      if (deltaX < clickDelta && deltaY < clickDelta && clickedTarget) {
        const href = clickedTarget.dataset.href;
        if (href) {
          window.location.href = href;
        }
      }
    });

    window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
      pressed = false;
    });

    sliderContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (pressed) {
        const newLeft = blockPos + (e.pageX - startX);
        innerSlider.style.left = `${newLeft}px`;

        if (e.pageX > oldx && banner.style.opacity < 1) {
          banner.style.opacity = parseFloat(banner.style.opacity) + 0.01;
        } else if (e.pageX < oldx && banner.style.opacity > 0) {
          banner.style.opacity -= 0.01;
        }

        oldx = e.pageX;

        checkBoundary();
      }
    });

    const checkBoundary = () => {
      let outer = sliderContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
      let inner = innerSlider.getBoundingClientRect();

      if (parseInt(innerSlider.style.left) > 150) {
        innerSlider.style.left -= 10;
      }

      if (inner.right < outer.right) {
        innerSlider.style.left = `-${inner.width - outer.width}px`;
      }
    };
```

```css
    .card {
      height: 300px;
      width: 400px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .banner {
      z-index: 2;
      height: 300px;
      width: 200px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: red;
    }

    .card:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: blue;
    }

    .card:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: rgb(0, 183, 255);
    }

    .slider-container {
      width: 80%;
      height: 350px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .inner-slider {
      width: 150%;
      display: flex;
      gap: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="banner" style="opacity: 1"></div>
    <div class="inner-slider" style="left: 250px">
      <div class="card" data-href="https://www.google1.com/"></div>
      <div class="card" data-href="https://www.google2.com/"></div>
      <div class="card" data-href="https://www.google3.com/"></div>
      <div class="card" data-href="https://www.google4.com/"></div>
      <div class="card" data-href="https://www.google5.com/"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```